# Different image using OpenCV in python and java

Tags: java, python, opencv

I'm using OpenCV to modify an image in python and in java. The code is very simple but I'm not getting the same result, why?:

**Python**:

```
img =  cv2.imread('sudoku.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,1,1,5,2)
printImg(thresh)
```

[image]

**Java**:

```
BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        op.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
                R.drawable.sudoku1, op);
Utils.bitmapToMat(bm, img);
Imgproc.cvtColor(img, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(gray, thresh, 255, 1, 1, 5, 2);
```

[image]

Comment: try witth a png or better, a bmp file (lossy jpg compression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'd tested some configurations and tried some workarounds. The issue seems related to how to load the image. Convert the image from `bitmap` to `mat` seems to affect the quality of the image as @berak said. I ended up using `Highgui.imread` to get the image.

If someone knows how to do it in a more android-friendly way I'd like to hear it.

Cheers.